# Impossibly slow WiFi on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

Someone gave me a Windows 8 laptop to "repair".
The WiFi connection is sloooow.

- when the laptop was new, the WiFi was ok
- now the WiFi connection is very slow: between 10 and 30 kB/s (tested with iPerf)
- wired connection is ok (gigabit link between 83 and 112 MB/s with my computer next to the laptop)
- I booted a Linux, and the WiFi bandwidth is ok
- I also tested two different external WiFi (a D-Link and an ALFA): same problem
- the same external WiFi keys work correctly with another Windows 8 laptop
- the slow speed is consistant with different routers (tested in 2 houses with different routers)
- tested in fail-safe mode: same problem
- I disabled the firewall: same problem
- as Spiff suggested, I used WiFi channel 1 instead of channel 11: same problem

So I can be (nearly 100%) sure this is not a driver problem, nor a hardware problem.
The problem is then only related to this specific Windows install. But why only for WiFi and not for wired connection ? The "WiFi stack" may be corrupted, but I don't think there is such a WiFi stack.

- I also removed the usual toolbars, adwares, etc
- and I updated the internal WiFi driver (nothing better)

What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem ?

Comment: I would help to know the exact make/model/revision of the internal Wi-Fi card, as well as for the two external devices you tried. Right now we only know the make but not the model, and only for the externals, not the internal (I'm assuming the original complaint was about an internal card).

Comment: it's a problem with the firewall. same situation here, when i turn it off it's speedy and when turn on it is slow as h*ll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 words: use system restore.

Comment: Other solution failed, so I did a system restore to a previous date. The WiFi is now working like a charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To isolate whether the problem is Windows itself as opposed to some software or setting specific to his "lived in" copy of Windows, boot off of an external USB, FireWire, or Thunderbolt disk that has a clean install of Windows 8, plus updated driver for the Wi-Fi card(s) on it. See if the problem happens there.

To see if it's an internal source of 2.4GHz or 5GHz interference, try connecting to an AP on a much different band/channel.  For example, I've seen video cards and monitors cause significant 2.4GHz interference *in certain resolutions / refresh rate settings*. It could be that your Linux video drivers were running the graphics subsystem differently than Windows does, which means different clock rates that would cause interference at different frequencies.  Try using different display resolutions and refresh rates to see if it is indeed the graphics chipset or display that's causing the problem.

It could be an internal interferer other than the graphics/display subsystems, but again may the Linux you booted either didn't initialize those other subsystems, or it wasn't running them with the same settings so they weren't generating the same kind of RF noise.

Oh, hey, another way to test the internal RF noise hypothesis would be to put one of the external USB Wi-Fi adapters on a decently long (say, 2m) USB cable and hold it up as far away from the system (and display) as you can, and see if the problem lessens significantly. Then see if the problem correlates to how close to the main system you hold the USB Wi-Fi adaptor.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Question updated about using another Windows 8, and using a different channel. The Alfa card already have a cable more than 1m long.

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT It doesn't matter how long the Alfa card's cable was, if you didn't hold it up and away from the (potentially noisy) system when you tested it. Did you hold it up and away from the system? Did it perform better when you did so?

I'd still recommend trying different display resolution / refresh rate settings as well.

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT So it sounds like you've narrowed it down to either (a) something about the hardware of this laptop or (b) something about the Windows install on this laptop, or (c) an interaction between (a) and (b). To help isolate those remaining variables, you should boot the problem laptop from a 100% clean Windows installation (I recommend using an external drive so you can leave the owner's "lived-in" Windows installation in place).

Comment: When the laptop was "fresh", the WiFi was okay. Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether you've tested against multiple WiFi routers... have you? It could have something to do with the Windows/router combination, perhaps some issue with the router WiFi that Linux recovers from but Windows doesn't.

Also, these won't solve your problem on their own, but here are two analysis tools I'd use in such a situation:

**Process Explorer** will give you a graph of the network activity of any given program. This can give visibility into how network traffic is shaped overall and per-program, correlate network activity with other system activity, see the particular patterns in your performance tests, etc. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

**NetMeter** is a very basic program with one awesome feature: a graph in your system tray that you can glance at whenever you're wondering whether/how data's being transferred: http://download.cnet.com/Net-Meter/3000-2155_4-10435551.html

Obviously these are just diagnosis tools but I think they could be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation of the problem is bad power settings on this laptop.

Go to Control Panel / Power Options / Change Plan Settings / Wireless Adapter Settings /
Power Saving Mode,
click on the "On battery" and "Plugged in" drop-downs and select "Maximum Performance" for both, then reboot.

Another possibility is that the [Quality of service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) (QoS) settings were loused up.
The QoS system service has to be running for this to be a problem.
(I am not sure that the fix described below does work in Windows 8.)

In regedit, go to the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Psched`.
If the sub-key Psched does not exist, create it.
In Psched, create a new DWORD value named `NonBestEffortLimit` and set it to zero (0).
Click OK.
Reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But alerady reseted and used the maximum perf settings. Also disabled QoS but only inside the card settings. Did it as you suggest with regedit. Nothing better.