# Windows 8 WiFi is slow if and only if power is unplugged

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I'm running two brand new ASUS T100CA laptops with Windows 8. I've had identical problems with them from the get-go, almost all WiFi related (Windows update won't work, Windows store won't load, SSH sessions disconnect). I finally discovered this peculiar behavior.

With power unplugged: Open chrome, perform a search, it takes 30 seconds for search results to load.

With power plugged in: Open chrome, perform a search, get results instantly.

I have tried plugged in and not plugged in several times and I consistently get this behavior on both of the new laptops. It seems like it must be a power plan issue, discussed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/608351/impossibly-slow-wifi-on-windows-8); but when I go to manage my power plan, **there are no options concerning the WiFi**.

I am using Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter Version 5.93.99.187.1 which is the latest version on the Asus webpage for these laptops.

How can I tell my computer not to put the WiFi into slow mode if I'm not plugged in?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @and31415 After a clean boot the problem seemed to go away but after 5 minutes of use it came back. Same symptoms. If I plug in the power everything is fast. If I unplug it it is IMMEDIATELY slow.

Comment: I think you meant you own a Asus T100TA. Anyway, I figured out the problem. I'll be posting an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WiFi driver you're using (Version **V5.93.99.187.1**) has this remarkably succinct description on Asus' website as "Enhance WLAN power consumption to increase battery life".

That being said, the problem seems to be with the drivers and a lot of T100 owners are facing the problem when using their WiFi adapters in 2.4 GHz b/g/n modes.

The fix seems to be to revert to **.168** Microsoft signed WiFi driver. The instructions for reverting back to MS drivers were given by `azazel1024` from [TranformerForums](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-book-t100-general-discussions/41759-wifi-tips-tricks-problems.html) (slightly edited by me).

1. Open the Network Connections window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → "**shell:ConnectionsFolder**" → <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Find your WiFi adapter and right click on it and select `Properties`.
   [image: WiFi adapter]
   Click the `Configure` button in the Properties window.
3. In the Properties box, select the `Driver` tab and click on `Update Driver`. Now click on the `Browse my computer for driver software` button and select `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer` and then select the Microsoft signed driver from the list. The one that has **(Microsoft)** next to the adapter name. Then, click `Next`.

For more information and troubleshooting, refer to [this thread on TransformerForums](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-book-t100-general-discussions/41759-wifi-tips-tricks-problems.html).

Comment: I think this solved the problem so I'll go ahead and accept the answer and come back if I have more trouble. Also, after upgrading to the Microsoft driver, Windows update will reinstall the Broadcom driver on your next update (if you allow it to). Make sure to hide the suggested Broadcom driver update so you don't break your machine again on next update.

Comment: @KulbirSaini you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Wireless Adapter Settings" under Advanced Power Options. It has settings for "Power Saving Mode" inside of which there are settings for "On battery" and "Plugged in". On my computer the "On battery" setting defaults to "Maximum power saving" and "Plugged in" defaults to "Maximum performance" which could explain your problem.

NOTE: I am using Windows 8.1 Update 1 instead of Windows 8 if that makes a difference.

Comment: As I stated in my post, there are no wifi options in power settings, including advanced power settings. I am using Windows 8.1 and windows update says I'm fully up to date. Might it be that I'm not running update 1? How could I tell this?

Comment: Update 1 should be included as part of Windows Update, so you should have it unless you ignored particular windows updates. What settings are listed under advanced power settings for you?

Comment: Balanced: require a pass on wakeup; Desktop background settings: slideshow; Power buttons and lid: lid close action, power button action, sleep button action; Display: turn off display after, display brightness, dimmed display brightness, enable adaptive brightness; Battery: critical battery action, low battery level, critical battery level, low battery notification, low battery action, reserve battery level.

Comment: My computer shows a lot more settings, including the wifi setting. Perhaps you could try (if you haven't already) the "Change settings that are currently unavailable"?

Comment: If that doesn't work you could also try switching your plan to "High Performance" which defaults the wifi settings to be maximum performance. The Balanced plan defaults the wifi settings to "medium power savings" on battery

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows 8.1 tablet that was exhibiting the same behavior.

It has the Realtek Semiconductor Corp version 3007.3.715.2014 WiFi driver.

So far what has seemed to have correct the issue is under Properties/Advanced/
Wireless Configure and change "Performance" to "Wifi" and then save the settings.

It's been a few hours since I made these changes and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I found an easier way to fix this (At least worked for me)

1) Click on the **Battery setting** (Notification Icon Area)

2) Click on **More Power Options**.

3) Go to your favorite Power Plan, and click on **change plan settings**.

4) Then, Click on **Change advanced power settings**.

5) Find **Wireless Adapter Settings** and click on it, then click on **Power Saving Mode**.

6) Finally, change your *"On Battery"* settings to **maximum performance**, then click **OK**.

Comment: As OP stated in the post, there are no wifi options in power settings, including advanced power settings. This is also a duplicate of the answer below.